# 21.10 blank screen on 2 differant laptops

Tags: boot, system-installation

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 21.10 on two laptops with the same results.
They would boot to a blank screen when the install finished and ask to remove the drive and press enter.
After booting up it presented a blank screen.
The hardware was a newer Lenovo and an older HP.
21.04 worked just fine so I went back to 20.04.3 LTS.Hopefully the new LTS will work on the next release.
Just a heads up

The output of `lspci -v | grep VGA` shows:

> 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
> [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev c1) (prog-if 00
> [VGA controller])

I am wondering if maybe it;s because it is booting to Waylon (?). I have no way to change it to X11 (?) as it boots to a blank screen.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your graphics card? Put the output of `lspci -v | grep VGA` and `inxi -G` to your answer. Thus we know what hardware and drivers you are using

Comment: Can you get to a TTY screen by pressing CTRL+ALT+F3?

Comment: 00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev c1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) and inxi -G was not found but could be installed.

Comment: BTW I could use the "try" just fine.

Comment: Yes I could reach the TTY screen by using CTRL+ALT+F3.

Comment: So you've got 2 different laptops wit the same AMD graphics card? I added it to your answer, since no one will start to browse the comments in order to gather all infos. You can use the **edit** below your answer to edit it ;-)